# Compiling a program using <graphviz/gvc.h>: undefined reference to `gvContext'

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I am working on some parts of a fairly large project that involves using GraphViz on C++, but I can't seem to use the GraphViz functions. My code is intended to generate a `.png` from `.dot` files automatically, but I keep getting "undefined reference" to 'functionName' (all functions that are related to the gvc.h include) when I try to compile it. I highly suspect that something is not linking during compilation, but I can't figure out what to do with the `CMakeLists.txt` and what I should link in the first place. I did, however, notice that there was a `gv.cpp` file in my `/usr/include/graphviz` folder, but I don't know if I'm supposed to somehow link that file or if it's something completely different.

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ag_gen.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `save_image_gv(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
main.cpp:(.text+0xf07): undefined reference to `gvContext'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xf27): undefined reference to `agread'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xf3c): undefined reference to `gvLayout'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xfc8): undefined reference to `gvRender'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xfef): undefined reference to `gvFreeLayout'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xff7): undefined reference to `agclose'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xfff): undefined reference to `gvFreeContext'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/ag_gen.dir/build.make:460: ag_gen] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:156: CMakeFiles/ag_gen.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:163: CMakeFiles/ag_gen.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:164: ag_gen] Error 2
```

Here is the problematic part of my code in main.cpp:

```
#include <graphviz/gvc.h>
bool save_image_gv(std::string filename){
    GVC_t *gvc;
    Agraph_t *g;
    FILE *fp;
    gvc = gvContext();
    fp = fopen((filename).c_str(), "r");
    g = agread(fp, 0);
    gvLayout(gvc, g, "dot");
    gvRender(gvc, g, "png", fopen((filename+".png").c_str(), "w"));
    gvFreeLayout(gvc, g);
    agclose(g);
    return (gvFreeContext(gvc));
}
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

# Uncomment for gcc
# set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc-8")
# set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++-8")

project(ag_gen)

set_source_files_properties(
    mem.c
    PROPERTIES
        COMPILE_DEFINITIONS UNIT_TEST=1
)

# Common compiler options among built types
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")

# Specific compiler options for Debug or Release builds
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g -O0 -ggdb -Wall -fopenmp -pedantic")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO} -g -Wall -fopenmp -pedantic -O1")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -O1 -fopenmp")

set(PostgreSQL_TYPE_INCLUDE_DIR "9.5")
set(PostgreSQL_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "10.1" "10" "9.5")

find_program(LSB_RELEASE lsb_release)
execute_process(COMMAND ${LSB_RELEASE} -is
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE LSB_RELEASE_ID_SHORT
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)

include_directories("/usr/include/postgresql")

# Apple has a different openssl directory when using brew
if(APPLE)
    set(BISON_EXECUTABLE "/usr/local/opt/bison/bin/bison")
    set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR "/usr/local/opt/openssl")
endif()

set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig")

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenMP)

find_package(BISON 2.4 REQUIRED)
find_package(FLEX REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

find_package(OpenSSL)
find_package(Doxygen)

pkg_check_modules(CMOCKA cmocka)
pkg_check_modules(CPPREDIS cpp_redis)

if(OpenSSL_FOUND)
    include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

# Enable thread-level parallelization if OpenMP is found.
if(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif()

if(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile @ONLY)
    add_custom_target(doc ALL ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen"
        VERBATIM)
endif(DOXYGEN_FOUND)

include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/")

file(GLOB ag_gen_src "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ag_gen/*.cpp")
file(GLOB utils_src "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/util/*.c" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/util/*.cpp")

########################
### Network Model Parser
########################

BISON_TARGET(nm_parser "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/parser/nm-parser/nm_parser.yy"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/nm_parser.c"
    DEFINES_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/nm_parser.tab.h")
FLEX_TARGET(nm_scanner "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/parser/nm-parser/nm_scanner.l"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/nm_scanner.c"
    COMPILE_FLAGS "-Pnm")
ADD_FLEX_BISON_DEPENDENCY(nm_scanner nm_parser)

#add_executable(nm_test ${FLEX_nm_scanner_OUTPUTS} ${BISON_nm_parser_OUTPUTS} ${utils_src})
#target_include_directories(nm_test PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/compiler/nm-parser")

##########################
### Exploit Pattern Parser
##########################

BISON_TARGET(xp_parser "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/parser/xp-parser/xp_parser.yy"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/xp_parser.c"
    DEFINES_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/xp_parser.tab.h")
FLEX_TARGET(xp_scanner "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/parser/xp-parser/xp_scanner.l"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/xp_scanner.c"
    COMPILE_FLAGS "-Pxp")
ADD_FLEX_BISON_DEPENDENCY(xp_scanner xp_parser)

#add_executable(xp_test ${FLEX_xp_scanner_OUTPUTS} ${BISON_xp_parser_OUTPUTS} ${utils_src})
#target_include_directories(xp_test PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/compiler/xp-parser")

####################
### Main application
####################

add_executable(ag_gen "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp"
    ${FLEX_nm_scanner_OUTPUTS} ${BISON_nm_parser_OUTPUTS}
    ${FLEX_xp_scanner_OUTPUTS} ${BISON_xp_parser_OUTPUTS}
    ${ag_gen_src} ${utils_src})
target_link_libraries(ag_gen ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(decode "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/tools/decode.cpp"
    ${ag_gen_src} ${utils_src})
target_link_libraries(decode ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES})

if(CPPREDIS_FOUND)
    #include_directories("${CPPREDIS_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    link_directories("${CPPREDIS_LIBRARY_DIRS}")

    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DREDIS")

    target_link_libraries(ag_gen cpp_redis tacopie)
    target_link_libraries(decode cpp_redis tacopie)
endif()

################
### Unit Testing
################

if(CMOCKA_FOUND)
    add_executable(dynstr_test ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/util/mem.c ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/tests/mem_test.c)
    target_link_libraries(dynstr_test ${CMOCKA_LIBRARIES})
endif()

# Files to be added to build directory
configure_file("config.ini" "config.ini" COPYONLY)

if(CPPREDIS_FOUND)
add_custom_command(TARGET ag_gen PRE_BUILD
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
                   ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/redis_scripts $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:ag_gen>/redis_scripts)
endif()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your CMake file doesn't appear to mention graphviz anywhere. Did you try linking to the Graphviz library? It should be located in `/usr/lib64/graphviz` or similar...

Comment: Since I'm fairly new to CMake, I don't know where to start when it comes to linking to libraries like Graphviz. Could you maybe lead me in the right direction? Looking under /usr/lib64/graphviz yielded files like libgvplugin_core.so, libgvplugin_core.so.6, libgvplugin_gdk.so and other similar files. Do I have to link all of these individually?

Answer (score 1):

Link `libgvc.so` with your binary as follows:

```
target_link_libraries(ag_gen PUBLIC gvc)
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually helped me in finding my own solution to the problem. May I ask (for future reference) how should one know what library names should be used? (In this case, gvc and cgraph were apparently needed)

Comment: Either: 1) knowing the library, 2) looking it up in the library documentation 3) looking at the actual library files that were installed and using `nm -D` to look through the symbols they define

Answer (score 1):

Using Botje's answer and [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61771170/configuring-cmake-with-graphviz-library), I was able to solve the problem. Here's what I did to my `CMakeLists.txt`:

I added `cgraph` and `gvc` in `target_link_libraries`.

```
target_link_libraries(ag_gen ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES} cgraph gvc)
```

And, voila! After this simple change, compilation was a success!

Comment: CMake does not use `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` for linking, so adding the `-l` flags there does not do anything.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I'm not sure what prompted me to do that. I've edited my answer to exclude the addition of `-l` flags.